# Couldn't start the dag in apache airflow MWAA

Tags: amazon-web-services, airflow

I am experiencing some weird error while starting my sample dag, it executed fine when i created it for the first time,but now executions seems to be failing.
Below is the error i am getting:-

[image: task error details]

Dag is just simple bash commands, which first print date followed by some more bash tasks.But its seems first task is getting failed before executions starts.

[image]

And Since its hasnt executed, it seems to not producing any logs as well.
[image]

Comment: What does it say in the "Log" tab?

Comment: @Emma - it doesnt seems to producing any logs. I have uploaded screenshot in the post

Comment: Here is the troubleshoot for that error on log tab. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mwaa/latest/userguide/t-cloudwatch-cloudtrail-logs.html#t-task-logs

Also, could you post your dag?